# Exception Handling in Beautiful soup/Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, exception, beautifulsoup

I have written code blocks which searches for some random text in the web page. The webpage has multiple tabs which I'm navigating using selenium. Here's the problem that the text I'm trying to find is not fixed in a specific page. The text can be in any of the tabs in the webpage. If the text is not found an exception is raised. If an Exception is raised it should goto the next tab to search. I'm facing difficulties in handling the exceptions.

Below is the code I'm trying out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.yxx.com/71463001")
a = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser")

try:
    head = soup.find_all("div", {"style":"overflow:hidden;max-height:25px"})
    head_str = str(head)
    z = re.search('B00.{7}', head_str).group(0)
    print z
    print 'header'
except AttributeError:
    g_info = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"details_readonly"})
    g_info1=str(g_info)
    x = re.search('B00.{7}', g_info1).group(0)
    print x
    print 'description'
except AttributeError:
    corre = driver.find_element_by_id("tab_correspondence")
    corre.click()
    corr_g_info = soup.find_all("table", {"id" : "correspondence_view"})
    corr_g_info1=str(corr_g_info)
    print corr_g_info
    y = re.search('B00.{7}', corr_g_info1).group(0)
    print y
    print 'correspondance'
```

When i Run this code i get an

```
error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\BS.py", line 21, in <module>
    x = re.search('B00.{7}', g_info1).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're getting that error because you're calling group on a re.search object that doesn't contain anything. When I run your code, it fails on that because the page you're trying to connect to isn't currently up.

As far as why your `except` isn't catching it: you mistakenly wrote two `except`s for only one `try`. The `try` is only going to catch any `AttributeError`s for the code *before* the first `except`.

By changing line 19 to `x = re.search('B00.{7}', g_info1)`, the code runs and returns `None` and `description` - again, because the page isn't currently up.

Alternatively, to achieve what I think you're going for, nesting the `try`/`except` is an option:

```
try:
    head = soup.find_all("div", {"style":"overflow:hidden;max-height:25px"})
    head_str = str(head)
    z = re.search('B00.{7}', head_str).group(0)
    print z
    print 'header'
except AttributeError:
    try:
        g_info = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"details_readonly"})
        g_info1=str(g_info)
        x = re.search('B00.{7}', g_info1)
        print x
        print 'description'
    except AttributeError:
        corre = driver.find_element_by_id("tab_correspondence")
        corre.click()
        corr_g_info = soup.find_all("table", {"id" : "correspondence_view"})
        corr_g_info1=str(corr_g_info)
        print corr_g_info
        y = re.search('B00.{7}', corr_g_info1).group(0)
        print y
        print 'correspondance'
```

Of course, this code currently throws a `NameError` because there is no info on the site from which to define the `corr_g_info` variable.

Comment: Thank you this works. Adding a nested try catch works.